# How to use Google translate API from code

Tags: java, android, google-translate

I am trying to create an app that send a word to *translate.google.com*, take the result of the translation and display it to the user. I composed the URL but I do not know how to extract the word/phrase from the webpage.

Example pseudo:
en is code for english and es is code for spanish

```
String from = "en";
String to = "es";
String word = "hello"; //this will be user input text really
String URL = "http://www.translate.google.com/#" + from + "/" + to + "/" + word;
```

Therefore the request URL will look like http://www.translate.google.com/#en/es/hello

I now need to be able to retrieve the information from the result box and place it in a String so I can display it to the user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google translate provide API for retrieving translations. You should use json object and GET request to the google translate server.
In [this link](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/using_rest?hl=it) you can find the official Developer's Guide with code examples.

Comment: As now Google translator API is paid, isn't possible to get the result through HTTP request?

Answer (score 2):

You will get json response from this

https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=en&tl=ru&dt=t&dt=bd&dj=1&q=hello

Here 'hello' is translated to russian

NO API KEY REQUIRED