# How to convert text in another language through coding?

Tags: javascript, java

I have keys and value pair I need to translate its value into another language.

> For Example :   "BLOOD_DONATIONS":"Blood donations",

I have too many keys, I have to convert its value in another language. (coding language java or javascript).

Comment: I can only guess that you are asking us for a translation tool/api which would be off topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: Use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388127/javascript-jquery-get-text-and-translate-it

Comment: In case of Java use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14789937/how-to-use-google-translate-api-from-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your key-value pair, I'd say that I hope at least the value is available in some language. You can try **Google Translate** ([They](https://ctrlq.org/code/19909-google-translate-api) say it's free ).